# Is it a normal phenomenon that CPU usage sometimes exceeds 100% after `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

I'm using ray to implement Ape-X. Following [this instruction](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example-rl-pong.html?highlight=openblas#the-distributed-version), I set `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`(I've verified that the Numpy I work with uses OPENBLAS via `np.__config__.show()`) and also have `tf.Session` configured as follows

```py
sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                             inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                             allow_soft_placement=True)
sess = tf.Session(config=sess_config)
```

Then I open `top`. Most of time, I can see all workers use less than 100%CPU. But once in a while, I'll see some use more than 100%CPU as the figure below shows. I'm wondering whether this is a normal phenomenon? If it's a mistake, what might the error be?

[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command#answer-145249 You seem to have multicore system while top shows the percantage of a single core. Thus values above 100% are valid and possible. I also encourage you to use htop instead.

Comment: Hi, I want to have each actor run on a core to avoid contention as [this instruction](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example-rl-pong.html?highlight=openblas#the-distributed-version) says. But I've done all the things it describes, still finding that the CPU usage of each actor sometimes exceeds 100%. Therefore, I suspect there is still potential contention but I don't know how to confirm it and how to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry that I cannot follow you. What do you suggest by other processes? COMMAND suggests the CPU is used by ray_worker, so what might the potential other processes?

Comment: Nevermind, my thoughts went the wrong way.